# React state is not being updated using useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I want to update a multidimensional array.

I have this state variable.

```js
const [travelledDataSet, setTravelledDataSet] = useState(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(solidDataSet)));
```

The structure of a solid dataset is initially.

```js
export const solidDataSet = [
    [
        [76.92025126928692, 31.815485031139886]
    ],
    [
        [76.92737521643127, 31.76427071949966]
    ],
    [
        [76.91587390417601, 31.75230203493911]
    ]
]
```

I have to update this data at a time interval once update function is triggered.

```js
const update=()=>{
        if(i>=dataSet[0].length) return;
        let tempData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(travelledDataSet));
        tempData[0].push(dataSet[0][i]);
        setTravelledDataSet(tempData);
        i++; // increment to next position
        setTimeout(update,100)
    }
```

Although state updates, but `travelledDataSet[0]` remains of size 2. And, `travelledDataSet[0][1]` is only being update.

***For example***

```js
// first__update__is
// -- travelledDataSet[0] --
[76.92025126928692, 31.815485031139886]
[77.06221522802589, 31.75536733328293]

// in__second__update
// --travelledDataSet[0]--
[76.92025126928692, 31.815485031139886]
[77.0603269528807, 31.75317784482199] -- only this is being updated each time.
```

To inspect why this is not working I created another variable (not react state) outside the update function.

```js
let ar=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(travelledDataSet))
    const update=()=>{
        if(i>=dataSet[0].length) return;
        let tempData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(travelledDataSet));
        tempData[0].push(dataSet[0][i]);
        ar[0].push(dataSet[0][i]);
        console.log("AR: ",ar[0],"Data:",travelledDataSet[0]); // ---- this is updating
        setTravelledDataSet(tempData);
        i++; // increment to next position
        setTimeout(update,10)
    }
```

after completion of the function, this code `console.log("AR: ",ar[0],"Data:",travelledDataSet[0])` prints.
[image]

You can see in the image below, `ar[0]` has a length 58 while `travelledDataSet[0]` length is only 1.

> Even this also doesn't worked `setTravelledDataSet(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tempData)));`

#### reproducible code:

```js
// it will render solid route indecating traveled route
    const [travelledDataSet, setTravelledDataSet] = useState(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(solidDataSet)));
    // update route -- only in development for simulation purpose
    let i = 1;
    const update=()=>{
        if(i>=dataSet[0].length) return;
        let tempData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(travelledDataSet));
        tempData[0].push(dataSet[0][i]);
        setTravelledDataSet(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tempData)));
        i++; // increment to next position
        setTimeout(update,10)
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        setTravelledDataSet(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(solidDataSet)));
        if(display)
            update()
    },[display])
```

Whenever `display` changes, i have to do the same thing from start. The component is about thousands line of code. I add the code here which can briefly explain the question.

Comment: It appears as though you *may* be enqueueing multiple updates in a loop, but with such a minimal code snippet it is difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Can you update to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code example? Using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` is a terrible way to clone objects and isn't recommended. It also seems like your update function always updates the first nested array with `tempData[0].push`. Why is each element of the outer array just a double-nested array?

Comment: @DrewReese `Can you update to include a Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible component code example?` I added the code snippet.

Comment: @DrewReese `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` here i am looking for solution, so i just tested this using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making a recursive timed call to update; calling `setTimeout(update, 10)` within `update()`? I have not seen this idiom before, and it looks fishy. Perhaps look at `setInterval`?

Also consider `useEffect` hook to handle side effects when the data changes, instead of an arrow function.

I think you should restructure this code. It is hard to read.

Comment: `I have not seen this idiom before` Ya, it's not a good practice. I used it to test if this solution will work for me or not. I am working with `mapbox-gl-js` there i got the problem.

Comment: So, the main problem is why state is not being updated while if i keen another array(not a react state) then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your "loop counter" `i` is redeclared each render cycle, i.e. each time the component renders `i` equals 1.

Since it still isn't clear to me why the state is so convoluted and what your state update is trying to accomplish here is what I think may be a simple "fix". Consume the `i` loop count as a passed parameter and initially pass `1` when initiating the recursion. You should also move the `update` function declaration into the `useEffect` hook to remove it as a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const update = (i) => { // <-- consume i loop counter
    if(i >= dataSet[0].length) return;

    const tempData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(travelledDataSet));
    tempData[0].push(dataSet[0][i]);
    setTravelledDataSet(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tempData)));
    
    setTimeout(() => update(1 + 1), 10); // <-- increment i
  }

  setTravelledDataSet(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(solidDataSet)));

  if (display) {
    update(1); // <-- initial seed 1
  }
}, [display])
```

Comment: `each time the component renders i equals 1.` I expect it to be one each time component renders. But, i don't want this to be one, each time component updates. It is working fine.

Comment: `let ar=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(travelledDataSet))` this solution worked for me temporarily. `// first__update__is
// -- travelledDataSet[0] --
[76.92025126928692, 31.815485031139886]
[77.06221522802589, 31.75536733328293]

// in__second__update
// --travelledDataSet[0]--
[76.92025126928692, 31.815485031139886]
[77.0603269528807, 31.75317784482199] -- only this is being updated each time. ` You can see here state updates, but not as i wish.

Comment: `let ar=JSON.parse` this array also has the same structure, here it worked fine. But, `travelledDataSet` also share the same structure, but here it didn't worked.

Comment: `You should also move the update function declaration into the useEffect hook to remove it as a dependency.` can you elaborate this.

Comment: @rahulkumar I'm not sure I follow the logic of expecting the component to not rerender when it updates. If you update state the component ***will*** rerender. Can you try creating a *running* codesandbox example that reproduces the issue for us to debug in?

Comment: @rahulkumar Sure, each render `update` is also redeclared, and since it is called in the effect hook callback it should be the dependency array. Do you not have have es-linting enabled or the the react-hooks linting rules applied? You should likely be seeing warnings like this.

Comment: i'll try to provide a codesandbox example, that can simulate the same problem.